# number list to datetime conversion in python

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert this list of time to datetime in python ?

```
time = [2014, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

so the result should be :

```
result = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unpack it.

```
result = datetime.datetime(*time)
```